# Hardware resolution scaling issue in Unity Android game

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I created an Android game using Unity5.4.0f3,

I made a scaling segment of code to adapt cards to different screen sizes that takes the width of the screen, then calculate the ratio between the screen width and a reference width (800) and then scale the cards on my screen to this ratio using `transform.localScale`.

On some devices the scaling doesn’t apply correctly and the cards are very big, and I get this warning `“Hardware resolution scaling not supported, falling back to software scaling (blit)”`, although scaling might be correct in other GUI objects

I searched this problem on the internet, as some suggested

1-  Upgrading Unity edition so I just installed the beta edition Unity2017.1.0b10, but this didn’t work for me 
This problem occurred on certain devices such as Galaxy Note 3 
If anyone has solved a problem like this before please share your experience.

[image: This Image shows the card at the center of the screen very large it should appear almost half this size when scaled]

I apply the scaling when a card is dragged from hand and released at the center of screen.

Here is the code:

```
public void Start()
    {
        width = 800f / Screen.width;
        if (width < 0.5f)
            width = 0.5f;
        this.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    }

public void OnEndDrag(BaseEventData eventData)
    {
        bool playedAsPlayPile = false;
        GameObject hand = PlayerManager.Instance.GetMe().transform.Find("Hand").gameObject;
        if (canDrag)
        {
            this.transform.localScale = new Vector3(width, width, width);
..... some other code
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably could be usefull to share the relevant scaling code

Comment: code added to post

Comment: Does the scaling always work unless you get that warning, are you sure there isn't an issue with your calculations?

I managed to find related [Unity bug report](https://fogbugz.unity3d.com/default.asp?753916_qo5pjd2k7vifdtq3) of this warning but only when software scaling isn't functioning correctly, and also a relevant [discussion on the forum](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/standard-shader-for-mobile.368672/) suggesting using different shaders to avoid this.

The bug is mentioned as resolved, it may have returned, or the issue might be in your calculations.

Comment: Do you happen to have a sample project we could try?